Parallel Trends Assumption in DiD: What happens when the pre-treatment trends are exactly the same?
WRT the testable parallel trends assumption (that is, that the pre-treatment trends of the treatment and control groups are the same): how do we move forward when the trends are the same (i.e. same slope & intercept = same line). Can we treat these groups as trending in "parallel"? And then calculate the treatment effect as any deviation that occurs post-treatment?
Edit: I'm interesting in conducting a DiD design, and the groups I'm studying have virtually the same trendlines before the intervention. How can I proceed?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

If pre treatment trends are parallel, we may be more confident that parallel trends would have also held in the treatment period if the treated group had not been treated, so that a DiD design would then be credible. Ultimately, it is just evidence for what you cannot observe in the treatment period, no "proof" for DiD validity.

The slopes are identical?

Can you cite where "parallel trends" assumption was invoked in the presentation of DiD that you trained to?\

The "parallel trends" "assumption" is rarely a requirement for conducting an analysis of pre-post interventional designs. Suppose our focus is to summarize the effectiveness of the intervention in a hypothesis testing framework. Notationally we might say $\mathcal{H}_0: \mu_0$ but what is $\mu$? It is a mean difference for pre-post differences comparing the intervention group to the control group.
Start with the picture.

The saturated model (with $Y$ the response, $X$ the binary treatment assignment, and $t$ the time point of assessment).
$$ E[Y|X,t] = \beta_0 + \beta_1 X + \beta_2 t + \gamma Xt$$
Predicts all timepoints perfectly:
$$\begin{array}{cc|c} 
X & t & \bar{Y} \\ \hline
0 & 0 & \beta_0 \\
0 & 1 & \beta_0 + \beta_2 \\
1 & 0 & \beta_0 + \beta_1 \\
1 & 1 & \beta_0 + \beta_1 + \beta_2 + \gamma \\
\end{array}$$
The $\beta_2$ handles regression to the mean, and the $\beta_1$ reflects imbalances in the groups, WLOG it is not a requirement for these groups to be homogeneous. Accordingly our earlier hypothesis identifies $\gamma$ as the target of inference, that which we called $\mu$ previously - the difference in differences (baseline to follow-up, difference between treated and control). If $\gamma$ is statistically significantly different from 0 we would infer that the intervention had some impact.
An undetected random slope is perhaps the closest we can come to questioning the validity of this design. Random slopes would infer that an individual's response at follow-up depends on their baseline value, and possibly treatment. An ANCOVA design can be assessed, or you can use a generalized estimating equation framework to account for the heteroscedasticity which, visually inspected by scatter plot, affects efficiency of results in proportion to its magnitude.
